# Maven: To get latest release mvn clean then mvn package working fine but mvn clean package not

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have single project setup where I am using `versions-maven-plugin` to get latest release.

When I ran `mvn clean` before `mvn package`, getting updated message which specify

```
[INFO] Updated old_version:jar:0 to version new_version.
```

But when I ran `mvn clean package` together then maven not able to get latest version and I got this error message

```
Could not find artifact old_version:jar:0
```

Why is this happening? If maven follows the order of execution then it should clean which updates the version first then package.
Any idea why `mvn clean package` command is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `mvn clean` and then `mvn package` is not exactly the same as `mvn clean package`.

The reason: Maven resolves all dependencies *before* it runs any of the lifecycles.

So if you run `mvn clean` and then `mvn package` you get:

- resolves dependencies
- updates your dependecy
- resolves dependencies
- package

but if you run `mvn clean package`, you get:

- resolves dependencies
- updates your dependency
- package (with the resolved dependencies from the beginning)

Summarized: You cannot update and use dependencies in the same Maven run.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. Can't I use one single command to achieve the same instead of two separate commands (i.e. mvn clean and mvn package)?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Then I want to clear another doubt in this, mine is single module project. For multi module project, it should not work also. But it is working absolutely fine for multi module with single command (i.e. mvn clean package).

Comment: Is the version of the dependency defined in the parent POM while the dependency is in the child project?

Comment: No, it is not mentioned in the parent pom.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-api</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>
</dependency>
and I am using "versions-maven-plugin" plugin with "use-latest-releases" goal in it.
once I ran "mvn clean package" it updates version with latest release which is not happening for my case.

Comment: Then I don't know.